# Environment variables for Pixar Renderman using ZSH in macOS Catalina

Tags: zsh, nuke, renderman

How to setup Environment variables for `RenderMan Pro Server` and `PrmanRender` ([RMANTREE](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/8.0/content/user_guide/prmanrender/setting_up_renderman.html)) installed on The Foundry NUKE 12v1.3, using `zsh` shell in macOS 10.15.5 Catalina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Environment variables can be set either permanently for the life-time of this shell process, for instance

```
export MYVAR=myvalue
```

or just for the execution of one command, for instance

```
MYVAR=myvalue mycommand
```

You can play around with this using the command `printenv`, which, given the name of an environment variable, prints its value:

```
export FOO=100
BAR=200 printenv FOO BAR
printenv FOO BAR
```

The first `printenv` will output 100 and 200, the second one will output only 100.

If you are only interested in zsh, a useful place to define environment variables permanently is `~/.zshenv`. Bear in mind that this file will be sourced by **every** zsh you are starting, even those which run non-interactively (i.e. as a script).

Comment: You do not have to put them into I file. It is up to you, how you organize it. I updated my answer to show one common way to do it, but you could also encapsulate the invocation of your application in a shell script and set the environment variables in this script; this is the way **I** would most likely do it, but in the end, it is a matte of taste.